# Header links: how to align it to opposite corners?

Tags: magento2.2, luma-theme

i have extended my default Luma header with new item:

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="callmeback" before="account">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Call me back</argument>
                   <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">checkout/cart</argument>

                </arguments>
      </block>
```

could any one advice how to align this new item into left side, as on screenshot below:
[image]

also, maybe anyone will give me tip how to add some icons to menu items? will really appreciate that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it is not on local, Could you please share URL ?

Comment: yes, sure: http://dev.oasys.kiev.ua/

Comment: i think you need to manage it by CSS, Because "header links" container width is not allow to float left

Comment: thanks, i guess so, but do not know how to do that) can you give me some hints where it should be changed?

Comment: for now you can add in ""http://dev.oasys.kiev.ua/static/frontend/lens/oasys/uk_UA/Mageplaza_SocialLogin/css/style.css".

Comment: yes it helped, many thanks! could you pls advice which magento theme css can i use, instead of extension?

Comment: great, its better if you can add a custom.css and add all your custom changes in that file.

Comment: you can also add custom CSS to "styles-l.css", changes will  be lost if upgrade magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add below CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    li.nav.item{
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
    }
 }
```

Comment: to app/design/frontend/lens/oasys/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less file?